# Mongo Operations getting starved

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, rabbitmq

Mongo db operations are getting starved in a rabbit mq consumer .

```
rabbitConn.createChannel(function(err, channel) {
channel.consume(q.queue, async function(msg) {
    // The consumer listens to messages on Queue A for suppose based on a binding key.

    await Conversations.findOneAndUpdate(
        {'_id': 'someID'},
        {'$push': {'messages': {'body': 'message body'}}}, function(error, count) {
            // Passing a call back  so that the query is executed immediately as mentioned in the
            // mongoose document http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is if there are a large number of messages being read the mongo operations are getting starved and executed when the queue has no more messages. So if there are 1000 messages in the queue.The 1000 messages are read first and then and then mongo  operation is getting called.

1. Would running the workers in a different nodejs process work  ?

Ans: Tried doing this decoupling the workers from the main thread, does not help.

2. I have also written a load balancer  with 10 workers but that does not seem to help, is the event loop not prioritizing  the mongo operations ?

Ans: Does not help  either the 10  workers read from the queue and only execute the findOneAndUpdate once there is nothing more to read from the queue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: There's really not enough to go on here, but try setting the pre-fetch count to something like 1 or 2 (you'll also have to acknowledge the messages when done) and see if that helps.

Comment: Also, is the mongo operation being called once per message, or once overall?

Comment: The mongo operation is  called once per message. I will  try  setting the prefetch  count.  I think I have found a solution. I tried using bulk write by writing 50  messages worked like a charm. Will  test some more. Thanks  for your prompt reply.

Comment: Essentially, with no prefetch and auto-ack set on, you have no message queuing. Messages will go straight from the publisher to the subscriber.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description of the problem, I think you have a case of no message queuing happening. This can happen when you have a bunch of messages sitting in the queue, then subscribe a consumer with `auto-ack` set to true and no prefetch count. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49672474/rabbitmq-consumer-overload/49675176#49675176) describes in a bit more detail what happens in this case.

If I had to guess, I'd say the javascript code is spending all of its allocated cycles downloading messages from the broker rather than processing them into Mongo. Adding a prefetch count, while simultaneously disabling auto-ack may solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thats what it was . Solved it !